# Sitemap submitted to HTTPS profile also influenced HTTP profile in Google Webmaster Tools

Tags: google-search-console, sitemap

Recently I upgraded a site to use an SSL certificate and noticed strange behaviour with Google Webmaster Tools.

Before starting the changes Google WMT Sitemap for `http://www.example.com` was showing as 920 pages submitted and 774 indexed.

After getting the site fully working with the SSL certificate, removing the sitemap for `http://www.example.com/` and submitting a new sitemap for `https://www.example.com/`, Google WMT Sitemap for `https://www.example.com` shows as 920 pages submitted and 799 indexed -- however, Google WMT Sitemap for `http://www.example.com` has changed to now show as 1840 pages submitted and 1573 indexed, so clearly this has been influenced by the recent submission of the `https://www` sitemap.

I would be grateful for your thoughts on why this might be.

The traffic (impressions and clicks per day) has remained roughly the same though has gradually moved from the `http://www.example.com` profile to the `https://www.example.com` profile as expected.

Answer (score 1):

Google treats the base domain as roll-up of all the subdomains.  I have a site with 10 subdomains each with about the same number of pages.  In Google Webmaster Tools it reports that the base domain has the sum of the pages on all subdomains indexed, even though the base domain doesn't have that many pages itself.

Based on your findings, it would appear that they treat the `http://` site as a roll-up of `https://` site as well.   Indexed https pages count towards the total of indexed http pages.

Comment: Did you find any Google documentation to support this? It would seem odd for Google to treat it as a roll-up for the Sitemaps but not for the search queries and traffic which have now fully transferred across from the HTTP profile to the HTTPS profile.